# How to compare each record with all other records in a same List Java?

Tags: java, list, foreach, arraylist, compare

I have a list :

```
List<BookDTO> bookList = libraryDTO.getBooks();

int bookCounter = 0;
for (BookDTO bookdto : bookList)
{
       if ((!errors.isEmpty() && !errors.containsKey("book[" + bookCounter + "].bookRefNo") || errors.isEmpty()) &&
           // do comparison for each record with other records in same list ) {

           errors.put("book[" + bookCounter + "].bookRefNo", messageSource.getMessage("bookRefNo.cannot.be.same", null, null));
        }

    bookCounter++;
    }
```

Now, I dont know how to do the comparison checking.. basically if there are matching records(records that having same value), I should get the key.

Comment: 1. your code does not compile. 2. What you are trying to achieve is not very clear.

Comment: Remove the calls to `isEmpty()` from the if statement - If I was writing the implementation, the first thing I'd (probably) do inside of `containsKey()` would be to check if the list was empty.  Also, you're going to be (you **should** be) getting the same error every time - capture it outside of the loop.  And I'm not sure what benefits 'managing' errors this way gets you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I guess your BookDTO has a bookRefNo property and you don't want to have more than one book with the same bookRefNo.

One solution is to rely on the fact that a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) contains no duplicate elements, so in your loop you could do something like this:

```
Set<String> bookRefs = new HashSet<String>();
for (BookDTO bookdto : bookList)
{
    if (!bookRefs.add(bookDto.getBookRef()))
    {
        // if we are here we tried to insert the same bookRef more than once...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ossummm.!! thanks @pgras ;-) its working great..and thanks for all of the commenters...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand if having two books with same values should raise an error (it seems so looking at your code) or if you want just to skip it while counting.

In any case you can't do it with a data structure that doesn't take into account a key without looping the whole collection for every element (that is **O(n^2)** complexity).

Could you use something more suitable like a set?

```
List<BookDTO> bookList = libraryDTO.getBooks();
Set<BookDTO> bookSet = new HashSet<BookDTO>(bookList);

bookCounter = bookSet.size();
```

Of course this assumes that `BookDTO` has correct implementation for `equals(..)` and `hashCode()`. You can even use a sorted set like `TreeSet<BookDTO>` but this would assume that `BookDTO implements Comparable<BookDTO>`.